# Cannot invoke length() on the primitive type int

Tags: validation, user-input, variable-length

I am trying to limit a users input for their student ID to a length of 8 characters but when I use input.length() it tells me I cannot invoke length() on a primitive type int. Is there any way I can easily fix/achieve what I desire another way? The error occurs on the fourth line.

```
input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Please enter your Student ID:  "); //Prompts for Student ID
int studentId = input.nextInt();
if(studentId.length() != 8)
    {
       System.out.println("Student ID must be 8 characters");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a simple function like this for validation

```
bool validId(int n) {
    if (n < 10) return 1;
    int length = 1 + numDigits(n / 10);
    if (length == 8) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Hope that helps

it also abstracts that out making it easier to read :)

Answer (score 0):

You defined `studentId` to be an Integer, and thus does won't have a `length()` method.

You could cast the `studentId` variable to a `String` and then use the `length()` method.

```
String student_id_as_string = studentId + "";
if (student_id_as_string.length() != 8) { 
  ... 
}
```